# Unable to access preloaded SQLite database file

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a pre loaded SQLite database for my android app. It is working fine when I test it on an emulator. But when I try it on a real device, it returns error saying:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: supplier

I have checked that database file and it definitely has the table 'supplier'.

I believe I have placed the .db file in the correct location (Initially misspelled and I got errors that DB not found. I fixed that and the error is gone since).

Using following code and dependency. Have attached a screen shot as to where the database is located now. Please advice.

```
dependencies {    
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
}
```

.

```
String tableName = "supplier";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //getting the database stored in assets folder
    try {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLiteAssetHelper.SQLiteAssetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
}

public void sqlTest(View v){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("QuoteDb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String[] inserts = {category, preferences.getString(category, "1")};
    //this line throws the table name not found error
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT quote FROM " +  tableName + " WHERE category=? AND rowid=? LIMIT 1", inserts);
}

private class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "QuoteDb.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: "I have checked that database file and it definitely has the table 'supplier'" -- on the device or emulator, or in your project? You might want to uninstall or "Clear Data" your app, then try installing your app again. With `DATABASE_VERSION = 1`, if there's already a database on that device or emulator, `SQLiteAssetHelper` isn't going to do anything, since it thinks you already have the database unpacked. If the database that's there happens not to have this table, that would explain your symptoms.

Comment: @CommonsWare By "has the table", I meant I checked the file on an sqliteBrowser, ensured it had the necessary tables and fields before pasting it into the assets/databases folder.

Comment: Then I stand by my recommendation: uninstall or "clear data" the app, so you are sure that `SQLiteAssetHelper` is going to unpack the file that's currently in `assets/` and not use some existing one that lacks your table. You might also get rid of `openOrCreateDatabase()` and use `SQLiteAssetHelper` consistently.

Comment: @CommonsWare I uninstalled and reinstalled the app on the device and same results. Also tried it on a device I've not installed before and also same results.The db contains a few tables. None of them is found when I test it.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I am trying to access the database in the assets folder. I am under the impression that that is the correct folder. Please correct me if the .db file should be some place else.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks will look it up. But not sure if that is just another way of doing what I am doing now or THE method. Under the accepted answer, one of the comment by CommonsWare is exactly what I am doing I believe.

Comment: Replace `this.openOrCreateDatabase("QuoteDb", MODE_PRIVATE, null)` with `getReadableDatabase()`, per my earlier comment about getting rid of `openOrCreateDatabase()`. [Here is a sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets-AndroidStudio) that uses `SQLiteAssetHelper`, in case that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Replaced to getReadableDatabase() and making all my query with dbhelper and it is working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the whole, if you are using `SQLiteAssetHelper` (or even `SQLiteOpenHelper`), use it consistently. Don't mix and match using the helper and accessing the database separately (e.g., via `openOrCreateDatabase()`). In part, that is because you want there to be only *one* instance of the `SQLiteDatabase` for this database at a time, shared by all threads, for synchronization purposes. That's easiest if you have one consistent spot of getting the `SQLiteDatabase`, and if you're using a helper, that helper should be the consistent spot. Typically, the helper turns into a singleton or is wrapped in a `ContentProvider`, so you can get to it from everywhere that's needed.

That being said, I can't quite explain your former symptoms, as I would have expected it to work. Though, since I use `openOrCreateDatabase()` approximately once a year, I don't have a ton of experience with your specific scenario.